# Validación Ajax con PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html5

Tengo un formulario donde se da de alta algunos datos (datos e imagen), el formulario con la acción PHP en mi formulario funciona y los agrega correctamente, pero no quiero que se refresque mi formulario si no solo los de alta, para esto utilizo AJAX. Ejecuto mi código y me agrega los datos excepto la imagen, ¿alguien sabe qué me hace falta?

Éste es mi código AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $().ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#loading').show();
    $('#result').hide();
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#form, #addproduct').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    })

    return false;
  });

})
```

Y el código de mi formulario:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="addproduct" name="addproduct" action="index.php?view=addreceipt" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >       
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> </div>

    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Folio</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="folio" id="folio" placeholder="se genera automáticamente" class="form-control" >
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Cliente *</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select name="cliente" id="cliente" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- NINGUNA --</option>
        <?php foreach ($clients as $client): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $client->id;?>"><?php echo $client->razon;?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
      </select>

    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fecha de Arribo *</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="fechadellegada" id="fechadellegada" placeholder="Fecha arribo" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Hora de Arribo *</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="horadellegada" id="horadellegada" placeholder="Hora arribo" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Operador*</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="operador" id="operador" placeholder="Nombre del operador" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Sello *</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="mysubmit" id="mysubmit" onclick="mostrar();">Agregar Solicitud</button>
    </div>
  </div>              
</form>
```

Comment: no entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Simplemente que no se refresque o recargue mi formulario cuando clickeo el boton, para eso lo estoy realizando con ajax, pero no me agrega lo que es el <input type='file' id='image' name='image'> en este caso es una imagen

Comment: edita la pregunta y coloca el codigo de tu formulario, por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un posible ejemplo para guardar datos e imágenes mediante `AJAX`.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="addproduct" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="mysubmit" id="mysubmit">Agregar</button>
</form>

<div id="result"><!-- Respuesta AJAX (¡IMPORTANTE!) --></div>
```

Como puedes ver he quitado el `action` de tu `form`, el `onclick` de tu botón, y la he añadido directamente al `AJAX`.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', '#addproduct', function() { 

   //Obtenemos datos.
    var data = $(this).serialize(); 

    $.ajax({  
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'tu_ruta.php',
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
              cache: false,
        processData:false,

        success:function(data) {  
            $('#result').html(data).fadeIn();
        }  
    });

    return false;
 });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas ejecutando el `submit`, simplemente crea un button y con `jQuery` (Que veo que lo usas) capturas todos los campos del formulario y lo envías de la siguiente manera.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#guardar', function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'ruta/guardar',
    data: {
        //aca colocaras todos los campos que deseas enviar al backend
        'nombre': $('#nombre').val(), 
        'apellido': $('#apellido').val(),
        'edad': $('#edad').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //si todo sucede correctamente tu escoges que haras
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //aca si algo sale mal
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear" class="form_con_select2">
        <input type="text" id="nombre"><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" id="apellido"><br/><br/>
        <input type="number" id="edad">
</form>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con serialize, no puedes enviar archivos, te sugiero que uses FormData:

```
$('form#elIdDelForm').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "tuRuta.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(datos) {
            $('#result').html(datos);
            ... etc
        }
    });

});
```